# Making featured image to show on home page

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am working on twenty twelve theme. Whenever I post an image gallery, it shows all of images including featured image on front page same as it looks inside. I wanted it to just show featured image on home page instead of showing all. I tried but no success.
Any help appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: Please review: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

Comment: do you generally not want to show images within the posts on the front page, or just not galleries?

Comment: only featured image on front page,, and whole post with gallery within posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to porvide more info, such as what you have tried so far.

have you used `the_post_thumbnail` function?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

Comment: I tried to find the code responsible for this, but I couldn't. But I'm sure that it is in functions.php. Maybe I can make a function to do this job, override the previous function responsible for displaying gallery on front page. Should I paste that code from functions.php on pastebin??